# Generating csv file from LWC in a managed package

Tags: lightning-web-components, managed-package, csv

I have a LWC with a button to download a list of records in a CSV file. My code is:

```
        const exportedFilename = 'issues.csv';
        if(navigator.msSaveBlob){
            navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, exportedFilename);
        } else if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i)){
            const link = window.document.createElement('a')
            link.href='data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(blob);
            link.target="_blank"
            link.download=exportedFilename
            link.click()
        } else {
            const link = document.createElement("a")
            if(link.download !== undefined){
                const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
                link.setAttribute("href", url)
                link.setAttribute("download", exportedFilename)
                link.style.visibility='hidden'
                document.body.appendChild(link)
                link.click()
                document.body.removeChild(link)
            }
        }
```

Where `doc` is the variable where the data is formatted. It works fine in my scratch org, the problem is when I generate a managed package with this code and install it in another org. In that case, when you click the download button, the file downloaded is always empty and 0B and I have no idea why. Do you have any suggestion, please?